# Scale Curve but not size of bevel

Tags: bezier-curves, transforms, bevel

I need to make target rings for an animation that pulsate a bit. The problem I am facing is, when I scale the individual rings of the target the effective thickness of the rings scale with it.

I need to scale only the outer diameter and the inner diameter stays relatively the same, so for example the difference of outer and inner needs to stay 0.1m regardless the scale of the ring.

I tried several things but nothing seems to do what I want.
Then I tried to do it CAD-style with a "sweeping" or as blender calls it "bevel" when working with curves. So I used a circle curve and as the object I tried using a rectangle. Though I dont change the size of the rectangle, when I scale the circle curve, the bevel seems to scale with it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just scale both the size (scale) of the curve and its bevel? with $1$ as base value, one would be the reciprocal of the other:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm!